# How to initialize a class as a frame tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I asked this earlier but I've narrowed down the issue, at least I think. I have this file

main_page.py:

```
class main_page(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
                                               
        canvas = Canvas(
            controller,
            bg = "#153246",
            height = 720,
            width = 1280,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        #canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

which is one of the many frames I need for my gui. And in a file called gui.py I have this:

```
class gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         
        container = Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {}
        self.curr_frame = None        
        
        #TODO: This needs to have the figma frames
        for F in (main_page, account_no_waiver):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(main_page)
```

the line `frame = F(container, self)` is meant to construct the frame so I can use it with the controller, but it is not making a frame.

I'm not exactly sure what to try as I don't have much experience with tkinter. I expect the frame to be added to my list of frames and I can then use a show_frame function, which just calls tkraise(), to raise the frame when I need it.

Comment: The code you posted won't run as posted. When I fix the obvious errors, the code seems to work fine.

Comment: *"but it is not making a frame"* - How do you know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't runnable as posted. However, the only real problem I see is that you're using `controller` for the parent of the canvas, rather than `self`. You should be using `self`, since `self` (the instance of `main_page`) is the frame that should contain the canvas.

You should rename the `root` parmeter to `parent` for clarity, and place the canvas in `self` rather than `controller`.

Also, you should use [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) naming conventions and capitalize the name of the class, and use camelcase. And finally, it's arguably better to use `super` when initializing the superclass.

```
class MainPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        canvas = Canvas(
            self,
            bg = "#153246",
            height = 720,
            width = 1280,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```